# What is the go-to directory for persistant "logistical" files?

Tags: files, filesystems, logs

I run a process which outputs data I would like to store somewhere so that another process, at some point, can read that file.

**Is there a traditional place where such files are stored?**

- I could use `/var/run` or `/run` but these are expected to be cleared when rebooting - I want my files to be persistent across reboots
- I could use `/myowndircetoryforpersistantfiles` and it would work, I am curious if there is something intended for such use

Maybe `/var/log`? (though this is not really a log file)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of data, you could use `/var/lib`, or `/var/tmp`. From the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard 3.0:

- [`/var/lib`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html):

  > This hierarchy holds state information pertaining to an application or
  >   the system. State information is data that programs modify while they
  >   run, and that pertains to one specific host. [...]
  >
  > State information should generally remain valid after a reboot, should
  >   not be logging output, and should not be spooled data.
  >
  > An application (or a group of inter-related applications) must use a
  >   subdirectory of `/var/lib` for its data. [...]
  >
  > `/var/lib/<name>` is the location that must be used for all
  >   distribution packaging support. Different distributions may use
  >   different names, of course.
- [`/var/tmp`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s15.html):

  > The `/var/tmp` directory is made available for programs that require
  >   temporary files or directories that are preserved between system
  >   reboots. Therefore, data stored in `/var/tmp` is more persistent than
  >   data in `/tmp`.
  >
  > Files and directories located in `/var/tmp` must not be deleted when
  >   the system is booted. Although data stored in `/var/tmp` is typically
  >   deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions
  >   occur at a less frequent interval than `/tmp`.

If you can consider the data to be "state information" for the group of applications comprising the two processes, then `/var/lib/<subdir>` seems to be a good fit. If not, `/var/tmp/<...>`.